# Pandas Dataframe, MOVE Specific Cell Value from one cell to Another with specific Columns (only)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I want to be able to copy the values under the allergy column there are three languages. I want use pandas Dataframes to move specific cell values data from the row English to french above it and dutch underneath it. And After it's been copied, I want to delete the row English.

**Note: Index is the languages below. They go in the order of French, English, Dutch, French, English, Dutch and so on. the Values of each are the typical responses are given under the column allergy**  note

(Brackets are where they are located in the excel)

```
    Index (COLUMN B      allergy ( COLUMN D)             COL B( COLUMN E).

    french               '' 

    english             'MAY CONTAIN: prawn' 

    dutch               ''

    french              ''

    english             'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

    dutch               ''

    french              ''

    english             'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

    dutch               ''
```

So again to summarise, copy specific cell values from English to Dutch and French Rows.

edit: The file has several columns however i'd like to only change the Column B and Column D of the excel file. I'd like the other Columns to remain the same. thus ignored. i.e anything after Column D.

**Desired output:**

(Brackets are where they are located in the excel)

```
Index (COLUMN B    allergy ( COLUMN D)          COL B( COLUMN E,) ....



french           'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'               

english          'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'  # remove

dutch            'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

french           'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts' 

english          'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts' # remove

dutch            'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

french           'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

english          'MAY CONTAIN: milk'  # remove

dutch            'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Afterwards, it Should look like this i want column b and d changed, in the excel.

**Final output:**

```
Index        allergy 

french      'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts' 

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have to use the .loc command. So

```
df.loc[french,'allergy (column)'] = df.loc[english,allergy ( COLUMN D)]
```

repeat the process till you are done, and then use the drop command.

```
df.drop('english',0,inplace=True)
```